# False positive kafka-authorizer.log when using listTopics() of KafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When using the [listTopics() method from KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#listTopics--) for each topic in the cluster, where the user has no authorization, the SimpleAuthorizer.scala creates a log line like the following in kafka-authorizer.log:

```
INFO Principal = User:user is Denied Operation = Describe from host = ip on resource = Topic:LITERAL:topicName (kafka.authorizer.logger)
```

**Is there a simple way to get rid of these "false positive" logs from listTopics() without loosing the real attempts to access a "foreign" topic?** Background: In a large shared cluster with lots of topics from different isolated development teams (a team has only a "describe" ACL entry for its own topics), this leads to a lot of security logs, when listTopics() is used, where there was no intention of "hacking".

Answer (score -1):

how about granting DESCRIBE acl-operation to all users?
like this:

```
/bin/kafka-acls --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zoo-1:2181 --allow-principal User:\* --topic \* --operation describe --add
/bin/kafka-acls --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zoo-1:2181 --allow-principal User:\* --group \* --operation describe --add
/bin/kafka-acls --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zoo-1:2181 --allow-principal User:\* --cluster \* --operation describe --add
```

Comment: The cluster is shared, and granting such wide Describe permissions would allow any user to see all topics and consumer groups on the cluster -- even those they don't have permission to use.  Sometimes that's not desirable.

For instance, if the users are customers, and they each have permission to access only their own topics like `customerFoo` and `customerBar`, then customer Foo shouldn't be able to Describe the cluster and see that Bar also is a customer.